# Vlookup using awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files in my linux server.

File 1

```
9190784
9197256
9170546
9184139
9196854
```

File 2

```
S NO.,Column1,Column2,Column3
72070,9196854,TGM,AP
72071,9172071,BGM,MP
72072,9184139,AGM,KN
72073,9172073,TGM,AP
```

I want to write a script or a single line command in bash using awk command, so as whatever the element in File -1 should match the same with column 1 in File -2 and print Column 1, Column2 and Column3. Also if any entry is not found it should print entry from file 1 and print NA in Column 2 and Column 3

Output : it should redirect the output to a new file as below.
new_file

```
9190784,TGM,AP
9197256,NA,NA
9170546,NA,NA
9184139,AGM,KN
9196854,TGM,AP
```

I hope the query is understandable. Anyone please help me on the same.

Comment: As you see 2 VOTES are there for closing this question so it is not clear, please add samples of input and output in your post too and let us know then?

Comment: What does the command `cat * | cut -d "|" -f 2 | awk '$1 {print substr($1,1,7)}'| head -5` have to do with `file 1` and the list of strings you show under it? Is that a command you're running on `file 1` to produce those strings as output (in which case just show us file 1) or is it the command thats generating `file 1` or something else? The columns you say you want to print don't match the output you say you want. Tidy up your question to be clear and consistent so we can help you.

Comment: Hi Ed, The cat * Command has nothing to do with file, it was just a way i was extracting the file nothing else. to make it more clear i have edited the question. Can you help now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

standard join operation with `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=","} 
       NR==FNR {a[$2]=$3 OFS $4; next} 
               {print $1, (($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA" OFS "NA")} file2 file1
```

substring variation (not tested)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=","} 
       NR==FNR {a[substr($2,1,7)]=$3 OFS $4; next} 
               {key=substr($1,1,7);
                print $1, ((key in a)?a[key]:"NA" OFS "NA")} file2 file1
```

Comment: Hi Karakfa, Thanks for the reply. i executed the command shared by you, gave the syntax error. awk 'Begin {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {a[$2]=$3 OFS $4;next} {print $1, ($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA" OFS "NA")}' test.csv gw_test_1.txt

Comment: awk 'Begin {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {a[$2]=$3 OFS $4;next} {print $1, ($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA" OFS "NA")}' test.csv gw_test_1.txt
awk: Begin {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {a[$2]=$3 OFS $4;next} {print $1, ($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA" OFS "NA")}
awk:                                                                                           ^ syntax error

Comment: hi Karakfa, I tried the code but it gave the output like below.awk 'Begin {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {a[$2]=$3 OFS $4;next} {print $1, ($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA" OFS "NA"}' test.csv gw_test_1.txt
9172070 NA NA
9172071 NA NA
9172072 NA NA
9171111 NA NA
9172073 NA NA
9172074 NA NA
9172222 NA NA
9172075 NA NA
9172076 NA NA
9172077 NA NA
9172078 NA NA
It gave NA NA everywhere,

Comment: Did you type `Begin` like in your comments or did you use the awk keyword `BEGIN` like in @karakfa's code? It's important to copy/paste a proposed solution to test it, not try to retype it by hand.

Comment: Hi Can you also suggest if incase my file 1 has input like 91968549898 and then i want it to just fetch the information of first 7 digits from file_2 and output should be printed like 91968549898,TGM,AP. what will be the code look like??

Comment: Thanks once again @Karakfa, but the code didn't worked as expected. Can you look into this and provide the tested code.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be awk? It's done with join:

Having two files:

```
echo '9190784
9197256
9170546
9184139
9196854' >file2

echo 'S NO.,Column1,Column2,Column3
72070,9196854,TGM,AP
72071,9172071,BGM,MP
72072,9184139,AGM,KN
72073,9172073,TGM,AP' > file1
```

One can join the on `,` as separator on the second field from the first file1 `-12` with removed the first header line `tail -n +2` and sorted using the second field `sort -t, -k2` with the first field from the second file `-21` sorted `sort`.

```
join -t, -12 -21 -o1.2,1.3,1.4 <(tail -n +2 file1 | sort -t, -k2) <(sort file2)
```

will output:

```
9184139,AGM,KN
9196854,TGM,AP
```